# How can I use Python's asyncio queues to simulate threads?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, websocket, concurrency, python-asyncio

I'm trying to simulate processing in threads by using asyncio.Queue. However, I'm struggling to turn a threaded processing simulation part to asynchronous loop.

So what my script does in brief: 1) receive processing requests over a websocket, 2) assign the request to the requested queue (which simulates a thread), 3) runs processing queues, which put responses into one shared response queue, and then 4) the websocket takes out the responses from the shared queue one by one and sends them out to the server.

Simplified version of my code:

```py
# Initialize empty processing queues for the number of threads I want to simulate
processing_queues = [asyncio.Queue() for i in range(n_queues)
# Initialize shared response queue
response_q = asyncio.Queue()
# Set up a websocket context manager
async with websockets.connect(f"ws://{host}:{port}") as websocket:
    while True:
        # Read incoming requests
        message = await websocket.recv()
        # Parse mssg -> get request data and on which thread / queue to process it
        request_data, queue_no = parse_message(message)
        # Put the request data to the requested queue (imitating thread)
        await processing_queues[queue_no].put(request_data)
        # THIS IS WHERE I THINK ASYNCHRONY BREAKS (AND I NEED HELP)

        # Do processing in each imitated processing thread
        for proc_q in processing_queues:
            if not proc_q.empty():
                request_data = await proc_q.get()
                # do the processing
                response = process_data(request_data)
                # Add the response to the response queue
                await response_q.put(response)

        # Send responses back to the server
        if not response_q.empty():
                response_data = response_q.get()
                await websocket.send(response_data)
```

From the output of the script, I deduced that 1) I seem to receive requests and send out responses asynchronously; 2) processing in queues does not happen asynchronously. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I was reading about `create_task()` in asyncio. Maybe that could be a way to solve my problem?

I'm open to any solution (even hacky).

P.S. I would just use threads from threading library, but I need asyncio for websockets library.

P.P.S. Threaded version of my idea.

```
class ProcessingImitationThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, request_q, response_q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.request_q = request_q
        self.response_q = response_q

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                (x, request_id) = self.request_q.get()
            except Empty:
                time.sleep(0.2)
            else:
                if x == -1:
                    # EXIT CONDITION
                    break
                else:
                    sleep_time_for_x = count_imitation(x, state)
                    time.sleep(sleep_time_for_x)
                    self.response_q.put(request_id)
                    print(f"request {request_id} executed")

# Set up
processing_qs = [queue.Queue() for i in range(n_processes_simulated)]
response_q = queue.Queue()
processing_thread_handlers = []
for i in n_processes_simulated:
   # create thread
   t = ProcessingImitationThread(i, processing_qs[i], response_q)
   processing_thread_handlers.append(t)
# Main loop
while True:
   # receive requests and assign to requested queue (so that thread picks up)
   if new_request:
       requested_process, x, request_id = parse(new_request)
       processing_qs[requested_process].put((x, request_id))
   ...
   # if there are any new responses, sent them out to the server 
   if response_q.q_size() > 0:
        request_id = response_q.get()
        # Networking: send to server
        ...

# Close down
...
```

EDIT: fixes small typos.

Comment: Your intuition that you need `create_task` is correct, as `create_task` is the closest async equivalent of `Thread.start`: it creates a task that runs _in parallel_ (in an async sense) to whatever you are doing now. But it's really hard to tell from your pseudo-code _what_ you want to do. Do you really need `processing_queues` to be a **list** of queues? How should `processing.queues.put(x)` even work, given that it's a list? Can you write a multi-threaded version of your pseudo-code, so that we can understand what it is you want in the first place?

Comment: fixed the code, it should've been: processing_queues[queue_no].put(request_info). All requests include info on which "thread" they should be processed.

Comment: Can you show equivalent pseudo-code that uses threads?

Comment: done! added pseudocode for the threaded version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition that you need `create_task` is correct, as `create_task` is the closest async equivalent of `Thread.start`: it creates a task that runs *in parallel* (in an async sense) to whatever you are doing now.

You need separate coroutines that drain the respective queues running in parallel; something like this:

```
async def main():
    processing_qs = [asyncio.Queue() for i in range(n_queues)]
    response_q = asyncio.Queue()
    async with websockets.connect(f"ws://{host}:{port}") as websocket:
        processing_tasks = [
            asyncio.create_task(processing(processing_q, response_q))
            for processing_q in processing_qs
        ]
        response_task = asyncio.create_task(
            send_responses(websocket, response_q))

        while True:
            message = await websocket.recv()
            requested_process, x, request_id = parse(message)
            await processing_qs[requested_process].put((x, request_id))

async def processing(processing_q, response_q):
    while True:
        x, request_id = await processing_q.get()
        ... create response ...
        await response_q.put(response)

async def send_responses(websocket, response_q):
    while True:
        msg = await response_q.get()
        await websocket.send(msg)
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to help. However, I'm facing some issues with websocket. I cannot recv after calling create_task twice with websocket as you suggested

Comment: @RytisJonynas What do you mean "I cannot recv"? Do you get an exception, does it not work in some way, what does your code look like and what steps have you taken to debug it?

Comment: Nevermind figured it out. Managed to block with another statement. Thanks for helping me out.